# Apply different function parameterisation to dataframe split using 'data.table' or 'by'

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to conduct stratified random sampling, across a dataframe strata, controlling the numbers of elements returned from each strata-level.

I can use a data.table approach, but only the first element of a vector of 'NumbeOfElements' is used.  How, in this context, do I step through the vector to return the desired number of rows (randomly selected)? I have tried various indexing options to no avail. I have also  tried a version via do.call(rbind(,by(...)but face the same challenge of varying the number of elements returned.  This is the data.table code so far:

```
library(data.table)
R1=function(X1,NumberOfElements){A=sample(1:nrow(X1),
            size=NumberOfElements,#how to step through this vector?  
            #print(NumberOfElements),#it is 'there'
            replace=FALSE);return(X1[A,])}

DF=data.frame( Site=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
              Depth=c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18))
DF2=data.table(DF)
DF3=DF2[,R1(.SD,NumberOfElements=c(2,1,0)),by=Site];DF3
```

I would like to DF3 to contain 2 random elements from Site A, one from Site B and none from Site C.  Guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably join the original table with your required sample size, then perform sampling for each site, as follows:

```
setDT(DF)
DF[DF[.(Site=c("A","B","C"), n=c(2,1,0)), on=.(Site), sample(.I, n), by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

Or storing your sample sizes in a named vector, you can perform the sampling by each Site

```
sz <- c(A=2, B=1, C=0)
DF[DF[, sample(.I, sz[Site]), by=.(Site)]$V1]
```

sample output:

```
   Site Depth
1:    A    12
2:    A    10
3:    B    14
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. You've got a mapping of `Site` to another variable (`NumberOfElements`); you should store this in a lookup table, either as a new `data.table` (more classic SQL style) or as a named vector (convenient in this case since your `Site` is `character` already)